# Flutter websocket Error. Connection to 'http:...#' was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: android, flutter, dart, websocket

I'm getting this error when trying to connect to the server I opened locally.
It converts ws to http. and put a # sign at the end.

**Socket:**
`final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://192.168.1.226:10600'));`

**Error: **
`Restarted application in 1.052ms. D/EGL_emulation(14743): app_time_stats: avg=8757.14ms min=3.84ms max=218720.27ms count=25 E/flutter (14743): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://192.168.1.226:10600#' was not upgraded to websocket`

The server was created with .net 4.8.

I would be glad if you help

I want to show the messages sent by the server in the application.